# How do I speed up my Cloudkit query

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I am working with Cloudkit to create an app allowing users to listen to my bands music. The below code works, but can take up to 30+ second just to load 5 songs. How can I improve my code to reduce loading time?

```
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
        self.pred = NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE")
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: "Radio", predicate: NSPredicate(value: true))
        self.queryOperation.qualityOfService = .UserInteractive
        self.queryOperation = CKQueryOperation (query: query)

        self.queryOperation.recordFetchedBlock = {
            record in

            self.songTitle = record.objectForKey("Titles") as! [NSString]
            self.song = record.objectForKey("Songs") as! [NSURL]

            self.songArray.appendContentsOf(self.song)
            self.songTitleArray.appendContentsOf(self.songTitle)

        }
        self.queryOperation.queryCompletionBlock = {
            queryCursor, error in
            if error != nil {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    print("\(error)")
                }
            }          
            else {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
                    self.updateViews()
                }
            }
        }
        self.publicDB.addOperation(self.queryOperation)
        })
```

Comment: You can't make the query any faster as that is limited primarily by your network connection speed and the amount of data you are transferring. You can make it *seem* faster by updating your UI as soon as you have retrieved the first song rather than waiting until all of the files have been downloaded as you do now

Comment: Thank you for the reply. To update the UI, do I move "self.updateviews()" to the record in section?  Does my code seem efficient?

Comment: Yes, that is the first place to start. I don't know exactly what you do in update views so it may need some tweaks. Your code is pretty starlight-forward; this isn't going to be the source of any delay

Comment: Great advice, thanks. I was also trying to pull the url of the song instead of the entire file to save data and time. Have I done that right?

Comment: Break your query down into two parts as you suggested. Get the titles, and some other meta data perhaps. As soon as they make a selection, start downloading while you display your meta data about the song, some graphics, a picture of a talking dog; anything to take their mind of the fact their waiting for the download :)